# How to get filename and path of file opened in Notepad using AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

How can I get the filename and path of file opened in Notepad using AutoHotKey?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: I've got a script that can give you the path for a folder open in Windows Explorer. Would that help at all?

Comment: That would definitely help.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use to run the file currently open in Notepad++ using Shift+Enter

```
#IfWinActive Notepad++
+Enter::
    Send ^s
    WinGetTitle, Title, A
    StringReplace, Title, Title,  - Notepad++, , All
    Run %Title%
    ;Notify("File Executed",Title,-2,"GC=555555 TC=White MC=White")
    Return
#IfWinActive
```